# detect missings (NA or 0) in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

i want to create a new variable in a data frame that contains information about the other variables.

I have got a large data frame. To keep it short let's say:

```
a <- c(1,0,2,3)
b <- c(3,0,1,1)
c <- c(2,0,2,2)
d <- c(4,1,1,1)

(df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d) )

  a b c d
1 1 3 2 4
2 0 0 0 1
3 2 1 2 1
4 3 1 2 1
```

Aim: Create a new variable that informs me if one person (row) has cero reports (or missings / NA) either in the variables a+b or in the variables c+d.

```
  a b c d  x
1 1 3 2 4  1
2 0 0 0 1 NA
3 2 1 2 1  1
4 3 1 2 1  1
```

As i have a large data frame i was thinking about the use of df[1:2] and df[3:4] so that i do not need to type every variable name. But i am not sure which is the best way to implement it. Maybe dplyr has a nice option?

Comment: `NA^(rowSums(df) == 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$x <- ifelse(rowSums(df), 1, NA)
```

**EDIT:** Answer to the updated question:

```
df$x <- ifelse(rowSums(df[1:2])&rowSums(df[3:4]), 1, NA)
```

gives,

```
  a b c d  x
1 1 3 2 4  1
2 0 0 0 1 NA
3 2 1 2 1  1
4 3 1 2 1  1
```

Comment: I need to collect certain columns only. This works out fine. Thx. 
df$x <- ifelse(rowSums(df[1:3]), 1, NA)

Comment: I noticed that my problem is more complicated. Gonna make an edit.